# I want to edit a video just like the one in this example but have no clue what to even look up to learn it

Tags: editing, fcpx

I want to edit a video with this same type of "endless paper" background. On screen graphics, and zooms.

I was trying by importing a large paper photo, then adding all of my on screen graphics to it scaled down, and then using a 3D camera to move between graphics on screen giving the video the same dynamic motion feel as the one linked in this inquiry.

This quickly turned into a nightmare task and I can not seem to find anything on google or maybe my phrasing is just terribly off to search for this.

PLEASE can someone at least tell me what it is I need to search to learn this. I can learn what I ever I need to editing wise but in this particular case I do not know what I do not know to even begin to learn.

MTIA

["Endless Paper background in intro. and Eased zoom ins and outs](https://https:/https://youtu.be/Ps34BrekZds)

Answer (score 1):

The youtube link doesn't work, but a lot of these are made using the iOS app which is literally called [Endless Paper](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/endless-paper/id1294105620)!

The illustrator draws it all inside the app, or imports sections from other drawing apps at each zoom level, and remembers where they plan to go with each pinch-to-zoom.

Then it is just filmed with a [rostrum camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rostrum_camera) over the tablet.

If you wanted to achieve a similar effect using video software, I would use After Effects with a series of parented comps.  I suspect Final Cut or Premiere wouldn't be the right tool for the job (but the actual right tool for the job is the iOS app mentioned).